# Trigger Azure Function from Service Bus topic without consuming Brokered Connections

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, servicebus

So, I'm analyzing whether using Functions to consume Service bus messages from a topic is viable.

The Service Bus pricing plan we chose has a limit on the number of 'Brokered connections' (max 1000) per month.

My understanding is that in the typical usage scenario the consumer/listener/subscriber connects to a topic and stays connected persistently, receiving multiple messages during a long period of time (a day, even a week) without breaking the connection, and that this is counted as 1 'brokered connection'. In the end you can receive thousands of messages on a single brokered connection.

How does this work with an Azure function binding? From what I read in the documentation, a function can be idle (ie not running), so it wouldnt be able to maintain this persistent connection.

Is there a separate component for Functions that keeps this connection alive listening for incoming messages? Or are we going to get billed for a new brokered connection each time the function goes idle and then restarts?

I'm including a screenshot of the current plan features:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/

[image: current plan features]

Later in the same link:

[image: Brokered connections overage]

---

edit

From [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-pricing-billing#brokered-connections):

> Service Bus charges for the peak number of concurrent brokered connections that exceed the included quantity (1,000 in the Standard tier). Peaks are measured on an hourly basis, prorated by dividing by 744 hours in a month, and added up over the monthly billing period. The included quantity (1,000 brokered connections per month) is applied at the end of the billing period against the sum of the prorated hourly peaks.

They specifically mention "1,000 brokered connections per month" in the last sentence.

This is an example:

> Each of 10,000 devices connects via a single AMQP connection, and receives commands from a Service Bus topic. The devices send telemetry events to an Event Hub. If all devices connect for 12 hours each day, the following connection charges apply (in addition to any other Service Bus topic charges): 10,000 connections * 12 hours * 31 days / 744 = 5,000 brokered connections. After the monthly allowance of 1,000 brokered connections, you would be charged for 4,000 brokered connections, at the rate of $0.03 per brokered connection, for a total of $120.

So I guess all of this is for 10.000 subscribers connecting to the topic at the same time during 12hs, if they connected for 24hs each day then 9,000 brokered connections would be billed (10,000 minus the included 1,000)?

In any case, I'm also trying to validate whether persistent connections are possible with functions (I'm told they are with webjobs).

Comment: have you found answer to this ? I too am worried about brokered connection and nobody seems to understand the cost in azure function trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Functions has a separate component known as the ScaleController that monitors your Service Bus for events 24/7.

Since the underlying SB message receiver in Functions is implemented in WebJobs, there will be a single connection that can retrieve multiple messages throughout the lifetime of the Function instance, although due of its current limitation, it is passing along those messages one at a time to your Function code for processing.

You are only charged when your Function code actually runs.  Here's a link that gives you an overview of the ScaleController:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#runtime-scaling

If you are anticipating relatively high load, have you considered using Event Hub instead of Service Bus? ServiceBus-Triggers in Azure Functions currently can only process one message at a time, which is not optimal for high load scenarios. Here's a GitHub issue that is opened to track this feature request: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1024

EventHub-Triggers can process messages in batches and that should give your more bang for the buck per Function execution. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs

Comment: Thank you Ling for your enlightening answer. Question: would each Function processing each message count as a Brokered Connection, or does the ScaleController maintain a persistent connection to the topic, hence being able to channel more than 1 message per connection? I was told this was how webjobs worked, 1 connection, multiple messages  (not talking about batches here, point taken and will look into Event Hubs.) Thanks.

Comment: The ScaleController (SC) does not maintain a persistent connection to the ServiceBus (SB) as the APIs SC are interested in are merely for discovering the a)message count and b)age of first message in the topic. This polling by SC occurs at an interval of 10 seconds. Using heuristics on a & b, SC will scale the number of instances up/down. Each SB-Triggered Function instance running on their on worker VM will then create a connection to retrieve a single message for processing. In Consumption Plan, if there are no errors, that connection will last for max 10 mins per Function instance.

Comment: Here’s an supplemental article with a sample EventHub perf run and its associated cost.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/09/19/processing-100000-events-per-second-on-azure-functions/

Comment: I need to clarify my earlier statement - you are correct in that the since the underlying SB message receiver in Functions is implemented in WebJobs, there will be a single connection that can retrieve multiple messages throughout the lifetime of the Function instance, although due of its current limitation, it is passing along those messages one at a time to your Function code for processing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ling, that completes the answer to my questions!

Comment: I have the same question regarding how the brokered connections are counted within the azure functions. I read the comments but i am not sure i understood. One question that it will make it clear for me: if in the queue arrive 1000 messages, triggering the function 1000, how many brokered connections are counted?